# Flutter - How can I call setState when a future builder has completed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget which is getting data from one of my other classes(booruHandler), I am using the search function for the future of a future builder but I need it to be called multiple times but only once the future builder has completed, I am using a similar future builder in another widget and getting it to call again using setState to increment widget.pageNum when an action happens. Is there a way to make it so the setState gets called when the future builder has finished building? I tried putting setState inside the futurebuilder and making it call if the connectionState is done but that doesn't work

```
class SnatcherProgressPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String tags,amount,timeout;
  int pageNum=0;
  int count=0;
  SnatcherProgressPage(this.tags,this.amount,this.timeout);
  @override
  _SnatcherProgressPageState createState() => _SnatcherProgressPageState();
}

class _SnatcherProgressPageState extends State<SnatcherProgressPage> {
  static int limit, count;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    if (int.parse(widget.amount) <= 100){limit = int.parse(widget.amount);} else {limit = 100;}
  }
  BooruHandler booruHandler = new GelbooruHandler("https://gelbooru.com", limit);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Snatching"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: booruHandler.Search(widget.tags,widget.pageNum),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
              switch(snapshot.connectionState){
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text("Snatching");
                  break;
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.data.length < int.parse(widget.amount)){
                    // Inc pagenum to get more data
                    // Call the writer function on all of the data
                  }
                  return Text(snapshot.data.length.toString());
                  break;
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  break;
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text("hmmmmmm");
                  break;
              }
              return Text("hmmmmmm");
            },
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very nice example could be like this:

```
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() => runApp(
  MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Setting a global key for navigator
  ),
);

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: Text('test')
          )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: showMyDialog, // Calling the function without providing it BuildContext
      ),
    );
  }
}

void showMyDialog() {
  showDialog(
      context: navigatorKey.currentContext,
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Text('Hello'),
        ),
      )
  );
}
```

showMyDialog() could be used everywhere including static Utility classes, db connection classes etc...

Answer (score -2):

Call back `pageNum` when updating

```
class SnatcherProgressPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final NumberCallBack onPageNumUpdated;
}
// ...
 setState((){
   onPageNumUpdated(/* the number */);
 });
// ...
```

```
typedef NumberCallBack = void Function(int number);
```

Or use [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt)

Comment: Where do i put the setState?? it only needs to be called when the future builder has completed building and a condition is met

Comment: Call `setState` when future builder connection state is done.

Comment: @Kahou you can't call a setState inside a FutureBuilder.